# How to open new incognito window with Javascript? (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to help my friend open a website in a new incognito window when he performs some mouse gestures (custom stroke in Mouse Stroke - Chrome Extension).

Comment: mouse stroke eh.

Comment: you say friend, eh?

Comment: This is a good question - not for the porn, but for the ability to have two separate sessions on the same website.

Comment: Google lead me here - I was looking for a way to open Facebook/Twitter in incognito windows from a bookmarklet for privacy. Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 32):

Chrome extensions with the `tabs` permission can use the [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create) method:

```
chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

However, to access it, you'll either need to write your own extension or find an existing one which provides a suitable hook (I don't know whether this can be done with "Mouse Stroke"—I'm too scared to look).

Comment: can you recommend a simple chrome extension?

Comment: @CarlosPliego: it's just HTML and Javascript—write one yourself?  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Comment: I dare say this is outdated. In the console it looks like the `windows` object doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Can you provide an example for what the manifest.json would look like?

Answer (score -1):

windows.create still works for me given I use it from the background script.