# New Chrome Incognito Window via HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, incognito-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open new incognito window with Javascript? (Google Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228118/how-to-open-new-incognito-window-with-javascript-google-chrome)

Is it possible to open a new incognito window to a URL of my choosing via either some attributes on a hyperlink or some javascript? If it is, how do I do it?

Answer (score 14):

There's an easy way if (and only if) you're developing an extension:

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  incognito: true
});
```

It requires `tabs` permission in the manifest, but that's it.

Note that the above has the user consent to allowing the extension to enter incognito mode, among other tab-related permission. I can't tell 100% whether you're developing an extension -- I assume not -- but in any case that's the extension solution and there isn't one otherwise.

Comment: Outdated. the windows object doesn't reachable anymore.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create

Answer (score 5):

Seems not.  You can not force incognito from within the html/js code.
You can only load the browser with

> -incognito

switch to force it to incognito on load.