# How to open an Incognito or Private Browser mode with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible to open a new browsing window in private browsing mode using AS3 for flash? I know by calling:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("adobe.com", "_blank"));
```

but is there a way to do this so that the new window/tab that opens is using private mode?

Comment: However true, that is still irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force a user to open the browser in private browsing mode.

This isn't just true for AS3/Flash, it's true across the board. Unless you're using code native to the browser (which you couldn't execute from AS3/JS), you can not do it.

This is, in part, because not all browser *have* private mode. Even those that do, have implemented it differently.

Answer (score 0):

See the following questions:

- [New Chrome Incognito Window via HTML/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363290/new-chrome-incognito-window-via-html-js)
- [How to open new incognito window with Javascript? (Google Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228118/how-to-open-new-incognito-window-with-javascript-google-chrome)

It would appear it simply is not possible in Chrome without being done through an extension with a certain permission. Flash is quite a bit more locked down than JS, so it is very likely impossible. A quick Google search for "flash open incognito" shows no relevant results, too, so that also makes me believe what you want isn't possible. I would assume it is similar for other browsers as well, though I did not search to be sure.