# Open a link in an Incognito Window in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, java

Is there any way to do this through Java or Javascript, given the link as a String?  I've been looking but I've only found topics about Android devices, I'm asking for a Windows PC.

I hadn't planned on learning how to write an extension with the proper permissions for Chrome for this, but if that's the only way then so be it.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @mjz19910 Edited title, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you have an extension with the permission to open tabs you can use `chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true})`

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228118/how-to-open-new-incognito-window-with-javascript-google-chrome

Comment: probably should have typed the title in to search first

Comment: I did find that but I've never messed with extensions before; I just wanted to write it in a standalone Java or Javascript executable, because I've worked with both of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run any executable including Chrome in JAVA:

If the path to the application is a system variable:

```
String location = System.getenv("APPVARIAVLE");
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(location).start();
```

Or if you want to use the fully qualified path:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\location\\MyApp.exe").start();
```

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for the process builder say that you can add parameters like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
```

The argument for incognito looks like it is: "-incognito" and to open a url just add the url: "example.com".

Which means that you can most likely can add the url and incognito arguments the following way to chrome in the arguments:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\YourChrome\\Location\\chrome.exe","-incognito","http://stackoverflow.com").start();
```

Comment: Yep, that's perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you for the nice explanations.