# Is it possible to have a form to submit to a new window using a new session?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

Sounds random but what I am trying to do it have a form with a few bits of data to be posted. I want the user to be able to hit submit multiple times and every time it opens a popup window. The pop-up window creates a session with the data but I don't want the next window to share the same session.

Not even sure if this is possible tbh but i was thinking i might be able to submit and it opens a new incognito window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228118/how-to-open-new-incognito-window-with-javascript-google-chrome

Comment: this opens a new window with a URL - however, I need a way of post data being passed over to it

Comment: If you want to open a new window with POST request, it's impossible. New window is always created with GET request, no POST allowed.

Comment: How about if i used iframes?

Comment: That's mostly the same as windows.