# How can we open Incognito mode in React js.?

Tags: reactjs

i want to open my new link in Incognito mode.

i tried :

`chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open new incognito window with Javascript? (Google Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228118/how-to-open-new-incognito-window-with-javascript-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function openUrlInIncognito(url) {
 window.open(url, '_blank', 'incognito=yes');
}


<button onClick={() => openUrlInIncognito('https://www.google.com')}>
  Open URL in Incognito
</button>
```