# How to open an incognito tab window with JavaScript/HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, incognito-mode

I have seen some websites that open a terms of service page that is in an incognito tab instead of a new tab or a "_blank". Is there a way to do this with HTML/JavaScript?
I can not use a Chrome extension to do this.

EDIT: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14BA6qLgd9thqYDZe5OiNxF7JDH9nXrTC/view?usp=sharing
Here is a recording for opening incognito. It is a bit weird and does not show the incognito new tab background but I tried downloading an extension, seeing if a search was showing, and looking if cookies would save and none of them did.

Comment: This seems like it isn't possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148136/how-can-we-open-a-link-in-private-browsing-mode

Comment: Can you provide an example of a webpage that does this? I've never experienced this kind of behavior.

Comment: I was connecting to a wifi network (which I do not want to name because of privacy reasons) when it asked me to log in to its network. It asked me to accept its terms of service, which was a clickable link, and the link opened up the terms of service in an incognito tab.

Comment: Is it possible that you were already in incognito mode and the window just opened in a new incognito window?

Comment: No, I am sure I was not.

Comment: I can send a recording maybe? Would that help?

Comment: Yes, that would be useful to make sure it isn't a bug with Chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253462/discussion-between-starryskies-and-michael-m).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open new incognito window with Javascript? (Google Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228118/how-to-open-new-incognito-window-with-javascript-google-chrome)

Comment: I can't use a chrome extension to trigger a windows.create. I am trying to do this within the browser.